# subpages are redirecting to the homepage

Tags: wp-redirect

A few days after installing 6.1.1 some pages started redirecting to the homepage.  I renamed .htaccess, disabled all plugins, and am using the 2022 default theme to try to locate the source of the 301 with no luck. So I checked curl, and found the source of the redirect was labeled "Wordpress". So I stopped the redirect and dumped the debug_backtrace in order to finally locate this thing. I'm guessing there is a canonical URL set up, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.
Any page with the URL [https://stgtrulite.wpengine.com/platform/[anything]](https://stgtrulite.wpengine.com/platform/%5Banything%5D) gets a 301 to https://stgtrulite.wpengine.com. The rest of the site works, and I can change the URL of the affected pages, but google has already crawled them with the URL.
Can someone please help me out?
Here is the dump:

```
Redirect attempted to location: https://stgtrulite.wpengine.com/
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /nas/content/live/stgtrulite/wp-includes/canonical.php
            [line] => 801
            [function] => wp_redirect
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://stgtrulite.wpengine.com/
                    [1] => 301
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => /nas/content/live/stgtrulite/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php
            [line] => 308
            [function] => redirect_canonical
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://stgtrulite.wpengine.com/platform/xxx
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file] => /nas/content/live/stgtrulite/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php
            [line] => 332
            [function] => apply_filters
            [class] => WP_Hook
            [object] => WP_Hook Object
                (
                    [callbacks] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [_wp_admin_bar_init] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => _wp_admin_bar_init
                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [10] => Array
                                (
                                    [wp_old_slug_redirect] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => wp_old_slug_redirect
                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                    [redirect_canonical] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => redirect_canonical
                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                    [0000000026d0f2cb000000001a0eef68render_sitemaps] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => WP_Sitemaps Object
                                                        (
                                                            [index] => WP_Sitemaps_Index Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [registry:protected] => WP_Sitemaps_Registry Object
                                                                        (
                                                                            [providers:WP_Sitemaps_Registry:private] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [posts] => WP_Sitemaps_Posts Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [name:protected] => posts
                                                                                            [object_type:protected] => post
                                                                                        )

                                                                                    [taxonomies] => WP_Sitemaps_Taxonomies Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [name:protected] => taxonomies
                                                                                            [object_type:protected] => term
                                                                                        )

                                                                                    [users] => WP_Sitemaps_Users Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [name:protected] => users
                                                                                            [object_type:protected] => user
                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                    [max_sitemaps:WP_Sitemaps_Index:private] => 50000
                                                                )

                                                            [registry] => WP_Sitemaps_Registry Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [providers:WP_Sitemaps_Registry:private] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [posts] => WP_Sitemaps_Posts Object
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [name:protected] => posts
                                                                                    [object_type:protected] => post
                                                                                )

                                                                            [taxonomies] => WP_Sitemaps_Taxonomies Object
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [name:protected] => taxonomies
                                                                                    [object_type:protected] => term
                                                                                )

                                                                            [users] => WP_Sitemaps_Users Object
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [name:protected] => users
                                                                                    [object_type:protected] => user
                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [renderer] => WP_Sitemaps_Renderer Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [stylesheet:protected] => 
                                                                    [stylesheet_index:protected] => 
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => render_sitemaps
                                                )

                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [11] => Array
                                (
                                    [rest_output_link_header] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => rest_output_link_header
                                            [accepted_args] => 0
                                        )

                                    [wp_shortlink_header] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => wp_shortlink_header
                                            [accepted_args] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                            [1000] => Array
                                (
                                    [wp_redirect_admin_locations] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => wp_redirect_admin_locations
                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [99999] => Array
                                (
                                    [0000000026d0f112000000001a0eef68is_404] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => WpeCommon Object
                                                        (
                                                            [options:protected] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => is_404
                                                )

                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [iterations:WP_Hook:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 0
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 11
                                    [3] => 1000
                                    [4] => 99999
                                )

                        )

                    [current_priority:WP_Hook:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                        )

                    [nesting_level:WP_Hook:private] => 1
                    [doing_action:WP_Hook:private] => 1
                )

            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [file] => /nas/content/live/stgtrulite/wp-includes/plugin.php
            [line] => 517
            [function] => do_action
            [class] => WP_Hook
            [object] => WP_Hook Object
                (
                    [callbacks] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [_wp_admin_bar_init] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => _wp_admin_bar_init
                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [10] => Array
                                (
                                    [wp_old_slug_redirect] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => wp_old_slug_redirect
                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                    [redirect_canonical] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => redirect_canonical
                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                    [0000000026d0f2cb000000001a0eef68render_sitemaps] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => WP_Sitemaps Object
                                                        (
                                                            [index] => WP_Sitemaps_Index Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [registry:protected] => WP_Sitemaps_Registry Object
                                                                        (
                                                                            [providers:WP_Sitemaps_Registry:private] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [posts] => WP_Sitemaps_Posts Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [name:protected] => posts
                                                                                            [object_type:protected] => post
                                                                                        )

                                                                                    [taxonomies] => WP_Sitemaps_Taxonomies Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [name:protected] => taxonomies
                                                                                            [object_type:protected] => term
                                                                                        )

                                                                                    [users] => WP_Sitemaps_Users Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [name:protected] => users
                                                                                            [object_type:protected] => user
                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                    [max_sitemaps:WP_Sitemaps_Index:private] => 50000
                                                                )

                                                            [registry] => WP_Sitemaps_Registry Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [providers:WP_Sitemaps_Registry:private] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [posts] => WP_Sitemaps_Posts Object
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [name:protected] => posts
                                                                                    [object_type:protected] => post
                                                                                )

                                                                            [taxonomies] => WP_Sitemaps_Taxonomies Object
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [name:protected] => taxonomies
                                                                                    [object_type:protected] => term
                                                                                )

                                                                            [users] => WP_Sitemaps_Users Object
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [name:protected] => users
                                                                                    [object_type:protected] => user
                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [renderer] => WP_Sitemaps_Renderer Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [stylesheet:protected] => 
                                                                    [stylesheet_index:protected] => 
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => render_sitemaps
                                                )

                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [11] => Array
                                (
                                    [rest_output_link_header] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => rest_output_link_header
                                            [accepted_args] => 0
                                        )

                                    [wp_shortlink_header] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => wp_shortlink_header
                                            [accepted_args] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                            [1000] => Array
                                (
                                    [wp_redirect_admin_locations] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => wp_redirect_admin_locations
                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [99999] => Array
                                (
                                    [0000000026d0f112000000001a0eef68is_404] => Array
                                        (
                                            [function] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => WpeCommon Object
                                                        (
                                                            [options:protected] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => is_404
                                                )

                                            [accepted_args] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [iterations:WP_Hook:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 0
                                    [1] => 10
                                    [2] => 11
                                    [3] => 1000
                                    [4] => 99999
                                )

                        )

                    [current_priority:WP_Hook:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                        )

                    [nesting_level:WP_Hook:private] => 1
                    [doing_action:WP_Hook:private] => 1
                )

            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [file] => /nas/content/live/stgtrulite/wp-includes/template-loader.php
            [line] => 13
            [function] => do_action
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => template_redirect
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [file] => /nas/content/live/stgtrulite/wp-blog-header.php
            [line] => 19
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /nas/content/live/stgtrulite/wp-includes/template-loader.php
                )

            [function] => require_once
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [file] => /nas/content/live/stgtrulite/index.php
            [line] => 17
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /nas/content/live/stgtrulite/wp-blog-header.php
                )

            [function] => require
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

And there's no redirection happening in the .htaccess file?

You may want to check the control panel at WPEngine and verify that there's not a redirection setup in their panel. It won't be a canonical URL issue as that doesn't affect redirection, only indexing in search engines.

If I enter https://stgtrulite.wpengine.com/platform/?123 it redirects to https://stgtrulite.wpengine.com/?123 - so there's still a redirect active somewhere.

As far as Google and their indexing, you can use their "remove from index" tool which would remove a URL from search results - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en

I'm not sure you actually want to remove it from the Index, just the redirection right? And if that's the case, and you don't have a plugin doing a redirect, then .htaccess or serverside redirection must be happening.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no redirects set up in wpengine. All plugins are disabled and the .htaccess file has been reset. I even switched to a default theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  The documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/) helped. When I flushed the rewrite rules with the problematic plugin installed the behavior didn't change. When I removed all plugins and the theme, THEN flushed the rewrite rules, the redirect finally went away. I was then able to track the plugin that killed the rewrite_rules setting in the DB by repeating this process.